# do.call cannot find function

Tags: r, do.call

First of all, sorry that I do not provide a fully reproducible example, but I'm using the devel version of a BioConductor package and the installation is a bit of a pain in the butt.

I am trying to use do.call to invoke functions based on a string I paste together. Like so:

```
testfunction <- function(){
  print("do.call is working")
}

do.call(paste("test", "function", sep = ""), args = list())
```

This prints:

> "do.call is working"

When I am trying to invoke my function of interest, like so:

```
for (dataset in unique(metadata[, 1])){
  replace_idx <- which(metadata[,1 ] == dataset)
  do.call(paste('curatedMetagenomicData::', dataset, ".genefamilies_relab.stool", sep = ""), args = list())
  if (length(replace_idx) > 0){
    # Do further stuff.
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error in
>   `curatedMetagenomicData::ZellerG_2014.genefamilies_relab.stool`() :
>   could not find function
>   "curatedMetagenomicData::ZellerG_2014.genefamilies_relab.stool"

**Invoking the function outside of the loop, without do.call, works.**

Could this be an environment problem of some sort? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might consider to use get(paste("test", "function", sep = "")) or if that don't work build the hole command as a string <- "do.call(....)" and use eval(parse(text=string)).

Comment: Perhaps use `f <- match.fun(paste0('curatedMetagenomicData::', dataset, ".genefamilies_relab.stool"))`, and see if you can grab the function, then use `do.call(f, args = list())`. Can't test.

Comment: I couldn't get anything of that sort to work. I managed to solve my problem, though, by omitting the "curatedMetagenomicData::" part. The simple do.call did the job, then. Thanks for your help, anyway :)